# Addition in SQL by month

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sum

I need to SUM column `something` by `month`:

```
   date     something
 2010-01-02  
 2010-01-03  
 2010-01-04  
 2010-01-07  
 2010-01-10  
 2010-01-12  
 2010-01-13  
 2010-01-14  
 2010-01-15  
 2010-01-16  
 2010-01-17  
 2010-01-18  3
 2010-01-19  1
 2010-01-21  
 2010-01-22  11
 2010-01-23  1
 2010-01-24  
 2010-01-25  
 2010-01-26  
 2010-01-27  
 2010-01-28  
 2010-01-29  
 2010-01-30  
 2010-01-05  5
 2010-01-06  8
 2010-01-09  
 2010-01-08  3
 2010-01-11  
 2010-01-01  
 2010-01-20  0
 2010-01-31  13
```

Output should be e.g. for JAN 2010 SUM OF SOMETHING 45:

```
   date     something
 2010-01     45
```

How to write SQL query for that?

Comment: I don't understand; when I add your `something` values I get `33` not `45`. Can you explain a bit more? Also, are your dates actually of the datatype `date` (or similar date datatype)?

Comment: `SELECT 45`. Otherwise, you'll need to be quite a bit more specific in what you're looking for. Perhaps some example data, table structure, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey! I have edited my question. @HoneyBadger Maybe I haven't c/p right data before, but this is how it should be: 3+1+11+1+5+8+3+13 = 45. My dates are type of : date ('yyyy-mm-dd')

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple aggregation based on the month of the `date` column:

```
select to_char("date", 'yyyy-mm'), sum(something)
from the_table
group by to_char("date", 'yyyy-mm')
```

This assumes the column `date` has the data type `date` (or `timestamp`)